# No longer able to connect to codespace

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, cs50, codespaces, github-codespaces

I created codespace via CS50.dev months ago, and have been using it since. However, suddenly I am unable to do so since two weeks ago. After logging on github (via cs50.dev), it shows "Codespace creation failed", the status "connecting...", and stalls. [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTD1y.png)

Alternatively, per this guide: https://cs50.readthedocs.io/code/ , I installed VS Code desktop, github codespace extensions, and tried signing in. This failed, with the message "Failed to connect to the codespace through the relay: invalid relay SAS", and "Source: Github Codespaces (Extension).[Screenshot on VS Code desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6L8g.png)

Tried asking around Gitter, however, did not help understanding, and hence resolving this.

Can anyone explain what's going on, and what I may do to resolve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github support team helped and solved the issue. Here's how:

1. Navigate to https://github.com/code50/ {CS50 codespace id}
2. Click on Code > Codespaces > +
3. List Wait for codespace to open

I was then redirected to rebuild the codespace.

Before that , I referred these posts on similar issues, tried some of the suggestions, however, did not resolve my issues. If anyone experiences similar issues, and what helped me doesn't help, these may offer some ideas:

i) community discussion post #62627 (https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/62627)

ii) community discussion post #15488 (https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/15488)

Hope this helps!